# mysql connection to remote database slow on vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I finally was able to set up vagrant with puphpet but I need the VM to connect to a remote server. When I load up the website it goes extremely slow making all the calls to the remote server.

I think they issue may have to do with the fact the VM creates a private network but I'm not sure.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the sql calls?

Comment: Slow compared to what?

Comment: Forgot I had this open. It was slow compared to a local mysql db on the VM or a mysql server on the same network. We decided to host a development database on the same network as our VMs but I just thought of setting up a vpn that we could use to connect to our remote mysql server that may make development on the remote faster if we need to.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - try:

```
skip_name_resolve
```

me helps. More details => [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854437/vagrant-remote-connection-to-mysql-outside-vagrant-ssh-connection/35874086#35874086)