# Vagrant - remote connection to mysql - outside vagrant ssh connection

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant

I have a problem with remote connection to mysql on vagrant. I am using MySQL with MariaDB.

I have user **root** with permisssions and server **'%'**.

In **my.conf** commented **bind_address** and removed **skip_networking**.

Locally it's worked fine. I turned off **firewal protection** in my **eset nod**.

When can I try connection:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306
```

shows:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

MySQL Workbench doesn't work too, simillar like database connection in PHPStorm.

```
[09:41 ]-[root@vagrant]-[/home/vagrant]
# lsof -i -P | grep :3306
47:mysqld    20792         mysql   22u  IPv6  51546      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Although the same call the above command works very long time - the result shows up after about a minute.

[image]

Below MySQL server variables:

```html
aria_block_size 8192
aria_checkpoint_interval 30
aria_checkpoint_log_activity 1048576
aria_encrypt_tables OFF
aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures 0
aria_group_commit none
aria_group_commit_interval 0
aria_log_file_size 1073741824
aria_log_purge_type immediate
aria_max_sort_file_size 9223372036853727232
aria_page_checksum ON
aria_pagecache_age_threshold 300
aria_pagecache_buffer_size 134217728
aria_pagecache_division_limit 100
aria_pagecache_file_hash_size 512
aria_recover NORMAL
aria_repair_threads 1
aria_sort_buffer_size 268434432
aria_stats_method nulls_unequal
aria_sync_log_dir NEWFILE
aria_used_for_temp_tables ON
auto_increment_increment 1
auto_increment_offset 1
autocommit ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log 80
basedir /usr
big_tables OFF
binlog_annotate_row_events OFF
binlog_cache_size 32768
binlog_checksum NONE
binlog_commit_wait_count 0
binlog_commit_wait_usec 100000
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format STATEMENT
binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling ON
binlog_row_image FULL
binlog_stmt_cache_size 32768
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client utf8mb4
character_set_connection utf8mb4
character_set_database latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8mb4
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert AUTO
connect_timeout 10
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
deadlock_search_depth_long 15
deadlock_search_depth_short 4
deadlock_timeout_long 50000000
deadlock_timeout_short 10000
debug_no_thread_alarm OFF
default_master_connection  
default_regex_flags  
default_storage_engine InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit 100
delayed_insert_timeout 300
delayed_queue_size 1000
div_precision_increment 4
encrypt_binlog OFF
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables OFF
encrypt_tmp_files OFF
enforce_storage_engine  
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expensive_subquery_limit 100
expire_logs_days 10
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
external_user  
extra_max_connections 1
extra_port 0
flush OFF
flush_time 0
foreign_key_checks ON
ft_boolean_syntax + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit 20
ft_stopword_file (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file vagrant.log
group_concat_max_len 1024
gtid_binlog_pos  
gtid_binlog_state  
gtid_current_pos  
gtid_domain_id 0
gtid_ignore_duplicates OFF
gtid_seq_no 0
gtid_slave_pos  
gtid_strict_mode OFF
have_compress YES
have_crypt YES
have_dynamic_loading YES
have_geometry YES
have_openssl YES
have_profiling YES
have_query_cache YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl DISABLED
have_symlink YES
histogram_size 0
histogram_type SINGLE_PREC_HB
host_cache_size 279
hostname vagrant
identity 0
ignore_builtin_innodb OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
in_transaction 0
init_connect  
init_file  
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm 10.000000
innodb_adaptive_hash_index ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions 1
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval 5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl OFF
innodb_api_trx_level 0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode 1
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval 3600
innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed OFF
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval 604800
innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed OFF
innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency 0
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 100
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances 8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_populate OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size 25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm INNODB
innodb_checksums ON
innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor HIGH_CHECKPOINT
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency 0
innodb_compression_algorithm none
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct 5
innodb_compression_level 6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max 50
innodb_concurrency_tickets 5000
innodb_corrupt_table_action assert
innodb_data_file_path ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir  
innodb_default_encryption_key_id 1
innodb_defragment OFF
innodb_defragment_fill_factor 0.900000
innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs 20
innodb_defragment_frequency 40
innodb_defragment_n_pages 7
innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy 0
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache OFF
innodb_disallow_writes OFF
innodb_doublewrite ON
innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm BACKOFF
innodb_encrypt_log OFF
innodb_encrypt_tables OFF
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age 1
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops 100
innodb_encryption_threads 0
innodb_fake_changes OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown 1
innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold 600
innodb_file_format Antelope
innodb_file_format_check ON
innodb_file_format_max Antelope
innodb_file_per_table ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit 1
innodb_flush_method  
innodb_flush_neighbors 1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops 30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_primary_key OFF
innodb_force_recovery 0
innodb_foreground_preflush EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF
innodb_ft_aux_table  
innodb_ft_cache_size 8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size 84
innodb_ft_min_token_size 3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit 2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table  
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree 2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size 640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table  
innodb_idle_flush_pct 100
innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed OFF
innodb_instrument_semaphores OFF
innodb_io_capacity 200
innodb_io_capacity_max 2000
innodb_kill_idle_transaction 0
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
innodb_locking_fake_changes ON
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog OFF
innodb_log_arch_dir ./
innodb_log_arch_expire_sec 0
innodb_log_archive OFF
innodb_log_block_size 512
innodb_log_buffer_size 16777216
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm INNODB
innodb_log_compressed_pages OFF
innodb_log_file_size 50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group 2
innodb_log_group_home_dir ./
innodb_lru_scan_depth 1024
innodb_max_bitmap_file_size 104857600
innodb_max_changed_pages 1000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct 75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm 0.001000
innodb_max_purge_lag 0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay 0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups 1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable  
innodb_monitor_reset  
innodb_monitor_reset_all  
innodb_mtflush_threads 8
innodb_old_blocks_pct 37
innodb_old_blocks_time 1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size 134217728
innodb_open_files 2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only OFF
innodb_page_size 16384
innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization OFF
innodb_print_all_deadlocks OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads 1
innodb_random_read_ahead OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads 4
innodb_read_only OFF
innodb_replication_delay 0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF
innodb_rollback_segments 128
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner 19
innodb_scrub_log OFF
innodb_scrub_log_speed 256
innodb_show_locks_held 10
innodb_show_verbose_locks 0
innodb_simulate_comp_failures 0
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay 6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_modified_counter 0
innodb_stats_on_metadata OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages 20
innodb_stats_sample_pages 8
innodb_stats_traditional ON
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output OFF
innodb_status_output_locks OFF
innodb_strict_mode OFF
innodb_support_xa ON
innodb_sync_array_size 1
innodb_sync_spin_loops 30
innodb_table_locks ON
innodb_thread_concurrency 0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay 10000
innodb_track_changed_pages OFF
innodb_undo_directory .
innodb_undo_logs 128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_atomic_writes OFF
innodb_use_fallocate OFF
innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit ON
innodb_use_mtflush OFF
innodb_use_native_aio ON
innodb_use_stacktrace OFF
innodb_use_sys_malloc ON
innodb_use_trim OFF
innodb_version 5.6.26-76.0
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id 0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size 262144
join_buffer_space_limit 2097152
join_cache_level 2
keep_files_on_create OFF
key_buffer_size 27262976
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size 1024
key_cache_division_limit 100
key_cache_file_hash_size 512
key_cache_segments 0
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_gtid  
last_insert_id 0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir  
lc_time_names en_US
license GPL
local_infile ON
lock_wait_timeout 31536000
locked_in_memory OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename  
log_bin_index  
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_error  
log_output FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes OFF
log_slave_updates OFF
log_slow_filter admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk
log_slow_rate_limit 1
log_slow_verbosity  
log_tc_size 24576
log_warnings 1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates OFF
lower_case_file_system OFF
lower_case_table_names 0
master_verify_checksum OFF
max_allowed_packet 16777216
max_binlog_cache_size 18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size 18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors 100
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length 1024
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads 20
max_join_size 18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data 1024
max_long_data_size 16777216
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size 104857600
max_seeks_for_key 4294967295
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth 0
max_statement_time 0.000000
max_tmp_tables 32
max_user_connections 0
max_write_lock_count 4294967295
metadata_locks_cache_size 1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances 8
min_examined_row_limit 0
mrr_buffer_size 262144
multi_range_count 256
myisam_block_size 1024
myisam_data_pointer_size 6
myisam_max_sort_file_size 9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size 18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options BACKUP
myisam_repair_threads 1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 134216704
myisam_stats_method NULLS_UNEQUAL
myisam_use_mmap OFF
mysql56_temporal_format ON
net_buffer_length 16384
net_read_timeout 30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout 60
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_mode  
old_passwords OFF
open_files_limit 4162
optimizer_prune_level 1
optimizer_search_depth 62
optimizer_selectivity_sampling_limit 100
optimizer_switch index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity 1
performance_schema OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size -1
performance_schema_digests_size -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size -1
performance_schema_hosts_size -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length 1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes 200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes 40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes 10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_stage_classes 150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes 178
performance_schema_max_table_handles -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes 50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size -1
performance_schema_setup_actors_size 100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size 100
performance_schema_users_size -1
pid_file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
plugin_maturity unknown
port 3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling OFF
profiling_history_size 15
progress_report_time 5
protocol_version 10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode OFF
pseudo_thread_id 56
query_alloc_block_size 16384
query_cache_limit 1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit 4096
query_cache_size 16777216
query_cache_strip_comments OFF
query_cache_type ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate OFF
query_prealloc_size 24576
rand_seed1 327991277
rand_seed2 782312767
range_alloc_block_size 4096
read_buffer_size 131072
read_only OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size 262144
relay_log  
relay_log_basename  
relay_log_index  
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery OFF
relay_log_space_limit 0
replicate_annotate_row_events OFF
replicate_do_db  
replicate_do_table  
replicate_events_marked_for_skip REPLICATE
replicate_ignore_db  
replicate_ignore_table  
replicate_wild_do_table  
replicate_wild_ignore_table  
report_host  
report_password  
report_port 3306
report_user  
rowid_merge_buff_size 8388608
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv  
server_id 0
skip_external_locking ON
skip_name_resolve OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_parallel_replication OFF
skip_replication OFF
skip_show_database OFF
slave_compressed_protocol OFF
slave_ddl_exec_mode IDEMPOTENT
slave_domain_parallel_threads 0
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet 1073741824
slave_net_timeout 3600
slave_parallel_max_queued 131072
slave_parallel_mode conservative
slave_parallel_threads 0
slave_run_triggers_for_rbr NO
slave_skip_errors OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum ON
slave_transaction_retries 10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time 2
slow_query_log OFF
slow_query_log_file vagrant-slow.log
socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size 2097152
sql_auto_is_null OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes ON
sql_quote_show_create ON
sql_safe_updates OFF
sql_select_limit 18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter 0
sql_warnings OFF
ssl_ca /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl  
ssl_crlpath  
ssl_key /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
storage_engine InnoDB
stored_program_cache 256
strict_password_validation ON
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm ON
sync_master_info 10000
sync_relay_log 10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone CET
table_definition_cache 400
table_open_cache 2000
thread_cache_size 8
thread_concurrency 10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_pool_idle_timeout 60
thread_pool_max_threads 1000
thread_pool_oversubscribe 3
thread_pool_size 1
thread_pool_stall_limit 500
thread_stack 262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone SYSTEM
timed_mutexes OFF
timestamp 1457385760.066998
tmp_table_size 16777216
tmpdir /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size 8192
transaction_prealloc_size 4096
tx_isolation REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only OFF
unique_checks ON
updatable_views_with_limit YES
use_stat_tables NEVER
userstat OFF
version 10.1.11-MariaDB-1~trusty
version_comment mariadb.org binary distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os debian-linux-gnu
version_malloc_library system jemalloc
version_ssl_library OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
wait_timeout 28800
warning_count 0
wsrep_osu_method TOI
wsrep_auto_increment_control ON
wsrep_causal_reads OFF
wsrep_certify_nonpk ON
wsrep_cluster_address  
wsrep_cluster_name my_wsrep_cluster
wsrep_convert_lock_to_trx OFF
wsrep_data_home_dir /var/lib/mysql/
wsrep_dbug_option  
wsrep_debug OFF
wsrep_desync OFF
wsrep_dirty_reads OFF
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround OFF
wsrep_forced_binlog_format NONE
wsrep_gtid_domain_id 0
wsrep_gtid_mode OFF
wsrep_load_data_splitting ON
wsrep_log_conflicts OFF
wsrep_max_ws_rows 131072
wsrep_max_ws_size 1073741824
wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle 0
wsrep_node_address  
wsrep_node_incoming_address AUTO
wsrep_node_name  
wsrep_notify_cmd  
wsrep_on OFF
wsrep_patch_version wsrep_25.11
wsrep_provider none
wsrep_provider_options  
wsrep_recover OFF
wsrep_replicate_myisam OFF
wsrep_restart_slave OFF
wsrep_retry_autocommit 1
wsrep_slave_fk_checks ON
wsrep_slave_uk_checks OFF
wsrep_slave_threads 1
wsrep_sst_auth  
wsrep_sst_donor  
wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries OFF
wsrep_sst_method rsync
wsrep_sst_receive_address AUTO
wsrep_start_position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
wsrep_sync_wait 0
```

Please help because I am stack totally.

EDIT//
Part of configuring vagrant.

```
network:
        private_network: 192.168.56.101
        forwarded_port:
            ssh:
                host: '22'
                guest: '22'
            www:
                host: '80'
                guest: '80'
            elasticsearch:
                host: '9200'
                guest: '9200'
            rabbitmq-management:
                host: '15672'
                guest: '15672'
            mysql:
                host: '3306'
                guest: '3306'
```

Comment: where are you running that `mysql` command? inside your mysql vm, or somewhere outside of the vm, trying to talk to mysql inside the vm?

Comment: Outside of the vm of course - inside vm mysql connects without problems.

Comment: then you need to redirect port 3306 on your host machine to the vm's ip. you're not running mysql on "localhost", which is the host, so there's nothing bound to port 3306 "outside" the vm.

Comment: But how? I am working on Windows.

Second - on my work I have vagrant too and there I can connect (via PHPStorm or CMD - ConEmu) to mysql outside of the vm without configuring forwarding. How? Why? Explain me how it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this :)

In my case after preparing all - bind address, skip-networking, user with privileges, off my anitivirus protection - problem was firewall on VM.

I typed:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

and it's working now. Hope this will help someone.

*The only slight problem is not the fastest connection time. Anyone know what it depends on?*

Problem above solved too by added option to mysql (from about 11 seconds for connection to milliseconds/immediately):

```
skip_name_resolve
```